# React: take data from array (only one ID and its details) and open it in a new page

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, datatable, onclick

I have 2 pages in React:  "Table" and "About".
"About" is empty yet.
On the page "Table" I have short array. And took some data from that array, put into table. In the table I have cells named "More" on each column.
I want when I click "More", it must take all data (+ "age" and "nickname" also) from array (only that special ID) and open in the page "About".
Can anyone help me? :) I know its hard. :(
Thank you in advance for your help. :)

```
  export default function Table() {
  const array = [
    { id: 1, name: "Oguztogrul", surname: "Tahirli", age: 36, nickname: "Bozqurd" },
    { id: 2, name: "Aqil", surname: "Qaraca", age: 25, nickname: "Hacker" },
    { id: 3, name: "Gunel", surname: "Youtuber", age: 22, nickname: "Shaman" },
  ];
  
  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {array.map((item) => (
            <tr key={item.id}>
              <td>{item.name}</td>
              <td>{item.surname}</td>
              <td>More</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Table() {
  const navigate = useNavigate() // if you using react-router v6
  const array = [
    { id: 1, name: "Oguztogrul", surname: "Tahirli", age: 36, nickname: "Bozqurd" },
    { id: 2, name: "Aqil", surname: "Qaraca", age: 25, nickname: "Hacker" },
    { id: 3, name: "Gunel", surname: "Youtuber", age: 22, nickname: "Shaman" },
  ];

  function actionWithData(item) {
    const querystring = Object.entries(item).map(([key, value]) => `${key}:${value}`)
    navigate(`/about/?${querystring.join("&")}`)
    
    console.log(item)
 }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {array.map((item) => (
            <tr key={item.id}>
              <td>{item.name}</td>
              <td>{item.surname}</td>
              <td onClick={() => actionWithData(item)}>More</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then in About page you can use get data from querystring

```
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams(); // from docs
  searchParams.get("id") // show id of item
```

I hope my solution will help you. Good luck in learning proccess!

Comment: I tried like this on page About. But didnt worked.   
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMl2G.jpg